# scraping web efficiently with python

Tags: python, performance, web-scraping

I've been experimenting with web content scraping lately using python. I've managed to provide the crawler a seed from which it starts to scrape each website's title, body content and every link that leads to another page.

Right now it makes sure every link is unique it inserts into the DB. This makes it awfully slow, but it's a must-have feature - I assume. There's no point in having hundreds of duplicates.

I want to know if scraping a page in ~100 seconds should really be this slow process and if so, how could I possibly make it faster. I'm really interested in the theory behind it.

Also, I'll provide my code just in case someone is interested in having a deeper look into it.

```
import requests as req
from pymongo import MongoClient
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
from time import time
from urllib.parse import urlsplit

client = MongoClient("ds055980.mongolab.com", 55980)
db = client.crawler
db.authenticate("swenn", "password")

global duplicates, new_links
duplicates, new_links = 0, 0
time_list = []

def get_data(soup):
    for script in soup(["script", "style"]):
        script.extract()

    if soup.title == None:
        return False
    else:
        title = soup.title.string

    content = soup.getText(separator=u' ')
    if len(content) < 15:
        return False

    content = content.replace("\n", "")
    title = title.replace("\n", "")
    rge = re.compile(r'\s+')
    content = rge.sub(" ", content)

    return content, title


def insert_data_into_db(soup, url):
    data = get_data(soup)
    if data == False:
        db.links.remove({"_id": url[0]})
        db.blacklist.insert({"address": url[1]})
        return False

    db.data.insert({"address": url[1], "title": data[1], "content": data[0], "time": round(time()), "in_use": 0})


def insert_urls_into_db(soup, current_url):
    global duplicates, new_links
    new_links = 0
    regex = re.compile(r'#.+')
    link_list = list(set(soup.find_all('a', href = re.compile('.+'))))

    for link in link_list:
        url = link.get('href')

        if "{" in url or "}" in url or "javascript:" in url or "mailto:" in url or url == "#" or url == "":
            continue

        if "://" in url:
            pass
        elif "//" == url[0::2]:
            url = "http:" + url
        else:
            parsed_current = urlsplit(current_url[1])
            if "/" in url[0]:
                url = parsed_current.scheme+"://"+parsed_current.netloc+url
            elif "?" in url[0]:
                url = parsed_current.scheme+"://"+parsed_current.netloc+parsed_current.path+url
            else:
                url_sub = current_url[1][::-1]
                url = url_sub[url_sub.index("/")::][::-1] + url

        if "#" in url:
            url = regex.sub("", url)

        if db.links.find({"address": url}).count() == 0:
            db.links.insert({"address": url, "time": 1, "in_use": 0})
            new_links += 1
        else:
            duplicates += 1

    db.links.update({"_id": current_url[0]}, {"$set": {"in_use": 0, "time": round(time())}})

def save_state_and_exit(urls):
    print("Saving document state...")
    for url in urls:
        db.links.update({"_id": url[0]}, {"$set": {"in_use": 0, "time": 1}})
        db.data.remove({"address": url[1]})
    print("Exiting...")
    exit()

def main():
    while True:
        urls = []
        try:
            documents = db.links.find({"time": {"$lt": round(time()) - 2592000}, "in_use": 0}).limit(10)

            if documents == None:
                print("Query did not match any documents. Exiting...")
                break

            for document in documents:
                db.links.update({"_id": document["_id"]}, {"$set": {"in_use": 1}})
                urls.append((document["_id"], document["address"]))

            t = round(time())

            for url in urls:
                print("current URL:", url[1])
                try:
                    html = req.get(url[1], timeout=5)
                    if html.encoding != 'utf-8':
                        html.encoding = 'utf-8'
                    html = html.text
                except (req.exceptions.Timeout, req.exceptions.ConnectionError):
                    print("URL",url,"doesn\'t respond. Deleting...")
                    db.links.remove({"_id": url[0]})
                    if db.blacklist.find({"address": url[1]}).count() == 0:
                        db.blacklist.insert({"address": url[1]})
                    continue

                soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
                if insert_data_into_db(soup, url) == False:
                    continue

                insert_urls_into_db(soup, url)

            print("vottis aega:", round(time()) - t,"sekundit","\t","uusi linke:","\t","duplikaate:", duplicates,"\n\n")
        except (KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit):
            save_state_and_exit(urls)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using "DOWNLOAD_DELAY" in settings of crawler, set download delay for making spider faster, but make sure website allows you, otherwise may be you will be blocked by source website very soon.

```
    DOWNLOAD_DELAY = 0 //as much as it is possible
```